# Can't run crontask in django project

Tags: python, django, cron, cron-task

I have django problem and I have problem with run the .sh file on server but not on local machine.

My .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.profile
cd /home/myproject/test
source venv/bin/activate
cd www
python manage.py make_import
```

I want to run this .sh file and run import with this line in crontab (Ubuntu):

```
10 8 * * * /home/myproject/test/www/crontab/test/make_import.sh
```

But this isn't working.

When I do this on my local computer via `python manage.py make_import` everything is fine.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: why dont you run the command normally from the terminal, and the cron will be added to crontab of ubuntu system

Comment: @Exprator you mean in this way: `10 8 * * * /home/myproject/test/venv/bin/python /home/myproject/test/www/manage.py make_import`?

Comment: Please define "is not working". Also make sure the command works on the server when executed directly from the shell...

Comment: no, just run manage.py make_import after activating your virtualenv and then go to www directory and run this command from terminal, the cron will be added to crontab of ubuntu, as you were doing in local